# Sorted byte arrays with unique values - best possbile compression

Tags: algorithms, coding-theory

I have byte arrays with following constraints:

- Length between 1 and 256
- Length median about 128, but I have to verify this on larger dataset
- Values are sorted ascending
- Values are unique

I am looking for algorithm for best compression of this data. Maximal uncompressed size for array if it is full is 256B. For median it is 128B.

For now best compression I know is to use bit-field to store if byte is in array or not, and I can omit trailing zeros. So for one array i will use `ceiling("max value" / 8) B`. For full array (or array containing 248) this will be 32B.

This will reduce size in general, but it is bad for sparse arrays with length < 32. I can use flag to store data compressed or uncompressed if it turns out that uncompressed array is smaller than compressed.

Is there any other trick/optimization/compression i can use to reduce size even more?

Is there any way to calculate theoretical boundary how much it is possible/not possible to compress this class of data so that I can measure quality of my approaches?

One short example of data to eliminate misunderstandings, please note that this array is shorter than expected array in data:
{ 0, 1, 5, 7, 88, 105, 233, 234, 235, 255 }

Comment: Each value of your array might be present or not, hence there are $2^{256}-1$ possible arrays (the empty array is disallowed). To recognize all of them, you need $\lceil\log_2(2^{256}-1)\rceil$ bits, which is equal to $256\mathtt{b}$, i.e. $32\mathtt{B}$. In other words, your solution is optimal in the _worst_ case. Of course, if you know the distribution of your arrays, then it could be possible to make the _expected_ size smaller.